# Download Update's fail (Unix File Permissions on /tmp directory)

Tags: 7, files, updating

When I goto `admin/reports/updates/update` select all and then hit the "Download these updates" I get the following  error message

> The specified file `temporary://filewq3Nao` could not be copied, because the destination directory is not properly configured. This may be caused by a problem with file or directory permissions. More information is available in the system log.
>   `http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/ctools-7.x-1.0-alpha4.tar.gz` could not be saved to `temporary://update-cache/ctools-7.x-1.0-alpha4.tar.gz.`

File System Settings can be found here: `admin/config/media/file-system`

`/tmp` is setup with `777` and I get NO errors on this page.  I attempted to create a `/tmp2` with `777` and that directory would fail the security checks.  I am on shared hosting.  There are directories in `/tmp` called `analog`, `awstats`, `cpbandwidth`, `webalizer`, `webalizerftp` which I assume are CPannel utilities:)

Comment: I also had the same problem for sometime after I switched servers. Changing the directory to ~/tmp/drupal saved me after hours of hair pulling.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have your own tmp directory, which is not /tmp but /some/path/to/your/directory/tmp. You wouldn't be allowed to create /tmp2 for sure :)

To find that out, go to admin/reports/status/php and look for _SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"], that will tell you where Drupal is located and from there, you should be able to build the path to your tmp directory.

Then set the temporary directory to that.

Comment: ~/tmp/drupal worked

Answer (score 1):

Made a directory under "tmp" and had to use "~/tmp/drupal".  Found this in some obscure part of the world